# Angle of rotation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What angle of rotation is produced by the transformation $w=\sqrt {z}$ at the point

(a) $z_{0} = i$

(b) $z_{0} = -i$

(C )$z_{0} =3+4i $

$f'(z)=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt {z}}$.

a) $f '(i)=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt {i}}$. =$\frac{\sqrt {i}}{2i}$=$\frac{i\sqrt {i}}{2}$=$ \frac{i^(3/2)}{2}$.= $\frac{1}{2}   (e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i})^{3/2}$

$Arg ( f'(i)) =\frac{ 3\pi}{4}.$
|f'(i)|=1/2

b)  $f '(-i)=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt {-i}}$. =$\frac{\sqrt {-i}}{-2i}$=$\frac{-i\sqrt {-i}}{2}$=$ \frac{(-i)^(3/2)}{2}$.= $\frac{1}{2}  (e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}i})^{3/2}$

$Arg ( f'(-i)) =\frac{- 3\pi}{4}.$
|f'(-i)|=1/2
c) I do not know how to complete .

-It is true the solution
 a and b?

I appreciate and thank who helps me

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of an issue, here: $\sqrt z$ is ambiguous on the complex plane.

Let's start by writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w=\rho e^{i\phi}$ for some non-negative real $r,\rho$ and some real $\theta,\phi.$ Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $-\pi<\theta\le\pi,$ but since we're trying to figure out what $w$ can look like, we cannot make any further assumptions about $\phi.$

Clearly, we need $z=w^2,$ so that $$re^{i\theta}=\rho^2e^{i2\phi}\tag{$\star$}$$ and applying the modulus to both sides of $(\star),$ we find $r=\rho^2,$ whence $\rho=\sqrt{r},$ and so $w=\sqrt{r}e^{i\phi}.$

Further assuming that $z\neq 0$ (so that $r>0$), we can conclude from $(\star)$ that $$e^{i\theta}=e^{i2\phi}.\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$

Here's where things go off the rails. Unlike the real exponential function, the complex exponential function is periodic, with fundamental period $2\pi i.$ Consequently, for any integer $k,$ we have $e^{i(\theta+2\pi k)}=e^{i\theta},$ so the best we can conclude from $(\heartsuit)$ is that $2\phi=\theta+2\pi k$ for *some* integer $k,$ so that $\phi=\frac12\theta+\pi k$ for said $k,$ and so $$w=\rho e^{i\phi}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\left(\frac12\theta+\pi k\right)}=(-1)^k\sqrt{r}e^{\frac12 i\theta}=\pm\sqrt{r}e^{\frac12 i\theta}.$$

The two possible definitions are known as branches of the function. What we will typically do, here, is to define $w=\sqrt{z}$ everywhere except on the ray starting at the origin and proceeding along the negative real axis (called a "branch cut"), using one of the two branches. In particular, since we'd like $\sqrt{z}$ to agree with the more familiar square root function defined on the non-negative reals, we will often choose what we call the principal branch: $$w=\sqrt{z}:=\sqrt{r}e^{\frac12 i\theta},$$ where $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0$ and $-\pi<\theta\le\pi$ as above.

The answer that follows will assume this is how it is defined for you, and may well be incorrect if it is defined in another way.

---

Okay. Now that the *caveats* have been taken care of, here we go. Given **any** $z$ not on the branch cut mentioned above, we begin by writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0$ and $-\pi<\theta\le\pi.$ Then we'll have $w=\sqrt{r}e^{\frac12 i\theta},$ and the (magnitude of the) angle of rotation will then be $$\left|\frac12\theta-\theta\right|=\frac12|\theta|,$$ in radians. In particular, this will be $\frac\pi4$ for the first two points, and $\frac12\arctan\left(\frac43\right)$ for the third.